# Running django tests results in duplicate column name id

Tags: python, mysql, django, testing

I'm creating a test for testing a helper function in Django. When running the test, I get the error "Duplicate column name ID"

I've tried to run `python3 manage.py migrate --fake-initial`, saw a solution here on Stackoverflow stating that it would work, but it didn't.

**Test.py**:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from reservations.models import Reservation, Table, Restaurant
from employee.helpers import *


class GetTablesWithCapacityTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Restaurant.objects.create(
            name="Test Restaurant",
            description="Restaurant for use in test",
            opening_time=12,
            closing_time=24,
        )
        Table.objects.create(
            restaurant=Restaurant.objects.filter(name="Test Restaurant"),
            number_of_seats=5,
            is_occupied=0
        )
        Table.objects.create(
            restaurant=Restaurant.objects.filter(name="Test Restaurant"),
            number_of_seats=4,
            is_occupied=0
        )

    def test_get_tables(self):
        tables = get_tables_with_capacity(5)
        self.assertEqual(1, tables.size)
```

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from guest.models import Guest
from django.utils import timezone


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Table(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    number_of_seats = models.IntegerField()
    is_occupied = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Reservation(models.Model):
    guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_of_people = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.start_date_time
```

**EDIT 2:**
Guest.models:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    reminder = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

The result I get when running the test is:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'table_id'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'table_id'")
```

EDIT 1:
**Complete stack trace:**
[image: What's out of the picture is "Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_stud_pu-29_trippinTacos'; database exists")"]
[image]
[image]

Oh yeah, I'm using MySQL, not the built-in Django SQLite.

I obviously wanted the output to be either a failed test or a successful test.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace?

Comment: @mfrackowiak I've edited the original post to contain the complete stack trace!

Comment: don't assign a foreign  key using a Queryset `restaurant=Restaurant.objects.filter(name="Test Restaurant")` but using an actual restaurant object (replace `filter` with `get` or add `.first()` to select the first object).

Comment: Include the definition of the `Guest` model and the migrations since there does not seem to be any duplication in the models shown.

Comment: The stack trace seems to show this is happening during test db setup. Can you create a very simple `TestCase` without `setUp()` method and a dummy test that just `self.assertTrue(1 == 1)` to see if that works?

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks, I'll use `.first()`. I tried to delete the `setUp()` and have only `def test_get_tables(self): assertTrue(1 == 1)` with the same error as above..

Comment: @drikgroten, @söze, @mfrackowiak it seems to be working now! I just deleted all my migration files and ran `makemigrations`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## FIXED

I deleted all my migration files and ran `python3 manage.py makemigrations`. That fixed it.